# How to use Python to send email via Microsoft Exchange Web Services API

Tags: python, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

With Exchange 2007 and Exchange 2010, Microsoft has introduced Exchange Web Services. This allows to perform many operations on the Exchange server using SOAP.

[Example SOAP Message to Send Email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa580238%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx)

Python has great SOAP libraries. I am assuming I can simply use these libraries to perform operations on the Exchange server correct?

Anybody has done this before?

Answer (score 0):

i would use suds for this.
download and documentation: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/
you will have to modify the wsdl file a little bit.

tutorial for php is located here: http://www.howtoforge.com/talking-soap-with-exchange
just use search form here or google :)

Comment: also, suds needs a bit of fixing to work correctly with EWS. For those still trying to get it to work, take a look here: [Python & SUDS](http://ewswrapper.lafiel.net/basic-info/python-suds/)